# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Every time I start xampp I got MySQL shutdown unexpectedly error. I have uninstalled and installed xampp, I have done mysql/data to mysql/data_old solution but it's a temporary solution. My database size is big and every time delete mysql/data it's not a solution. I need a permanent solution.
Xampp version: 3.3.0
Window 11

[image]

```
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2023-05-09  9:51:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 532308390; transaction id 8970
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-09  9:51:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```